# Javascript calculations of percentages are off

Tags: javascript, html

I have a some JavaScript that I use to calculate a percentage discount on a form field that holds a total value.

```js
var thirteen = 10;
var percent_discount = (thirteen) * 0.01;
var percent_discount_final = (382.50 * (percent_discount));
console.log(percent_discount_final.toFixed(2));
```

The calculation is outputted at 38.24??

Why is that happening?

[image]

Comment: Try `percent_discount_final = Math.round(value of some form field * percent discount);`

Comment: That doesn't work. If my total is 382.50 and I am calculating 10% off of that, it shows the result as 38.20

Comment: `(10 * 0.01 * 382.50).toFixed(2)` - this returns 38.25 on the console, just tried it

Comment: @BrianFleishman There is no way we can provide an answer without knowing the values of theses items.

Comment: The values are dynamic because it depends on what the user types in on the web form. The values are not important really because that caluclation in the javascript is off. That is what I am trying to determine the cause of. 10% of 250 should be 25 but the script calculate 24.99 ??

Comment: So is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: @BrianFleishman It doesn't matter that the values are dynamic in regards to your question, in fact it should of been disregarded in the first place. You are asking why you code appears to be calculating off in a certain case, hence for us to explain it and understand it easily without assumptions, it's best to actually tell us the input. No JavaScript is not wrong as `250*0.1` is `25`, for your input we don't know if you are making a mistake in that regards or not.

Comment: With what you just updated, the result is `38.25`

Comment: @BrianFleishman In regards to that it is returning the value `38.25` (*updated code to snippet for clarity*).

Comment: Looks like he solved it :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to accurately explain what is going on here I guess. I agree that my code should calcutate the result of 38.25, but it is calculating 38.24 instead,

Comment: The code you have proved produces **38.25** in Chrome, IE and Firefox. Provide the code you have used to produce the image.

Answer (score 0):

Well, should be the full value minus the discount - third line being:

```
var percent_discount_final = value_of_some_form_field - (value_of_some_form_field  * percent_discount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost figured out the right multiplier, but you forgot to subtract from `1`, so you are multiplying by `0.1` instead of `0.9`.

Here is an example of how to subtract any percentage from a number.

```
const subtractPercent = (value, percentage) => {
    const multiplier = 1 - (percentage / 100);
    return value * multiplier;
};

subtractPercent(250, 10);   // 225
subtractPercent(250, 3);    // 242.5
```

Similar to yours, this function assumes that `value` is positive, for simplicity's sake. Negative values will add instead of subtract.

```
subtractPercent(250, -10);  // 275
subtractPercent(-250, 10);  // -225
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing 'var percent_discount = (thirteen) * .01;' to 'var percent_discount = (thirteen) * 0.01;' solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

fun fact - float type is not precise. it came from large numbers theory, and by design it is approximation. that is why several languages provide also types like monetary etc. and for languages that don't, we calculate all monetary stuff on integers. it's not javascript related "bug", it is computer science "feature" :)

how to calculate monetary stuff on integers? well, you have to create/emulate new type. general idea is

- convert all data from float to integer multiplying also by 100
- perform all calculations on integers (no single float can be mixed, or the result will also be converted to float)
- at the end (in most cases it's on data output / user interface) divide every value by 100

yes, in 21 century it looks plain stupid, but there is no magic you can use, when your tool (JS) doesn't have dedicated data type for monetary calculations. you have to build it.

is JS the only language involved in this project? if there is some for example some SQL db, most of them have dedicated monetary types, so you can make all your calculations on database side.